# Cannot add a Lambda target to an existing CloudWatch rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I want to add a Lambda target to an existing CloudWatch rule. I used the following to refer to the existing rule:

```
rule = events.Rule.from_event_rule_arn(self, "Rule",event_rule_arn='')
```

Later I add a target with:

```
rule.add_target(targets.LambdaFunction(lambdaFn))
```

When I execute a `cdk synth` or `deploy`, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: '+' object has no attribute 'add_target'

I know the `IRule` element does not have that method but I cannot find a clear way how to achieve what I need.

I also try using event source in Lambda but got the following error:

> Unrecognized event source, must be kinesis, dynamodb stream or sqs.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. You need to reference the lambda function and manage the rule from the stack to which the rule belongs.

Answer (score 0):

As MilanG suggests, it is not possible to do.

My use case needs to create several Lambda functions and set the same trigger to them and CloudWatch Rules is not a fit for it because of a 5 targets per rule hard limit. I use SNS instead as follows:

```
sns_topic = aws_sns.Topic.from_topic_arn(scope, id, topic_arn=config)

lambdaFn.add_event_source(aws_lambda_event_sources.SnsEventSource(sns_topic))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Lambda function as a target to pre-existing Rule can be done as of AWS CDK version 2.66.

```
rule = events.Rule.from_event_rule_arn(scope=self, id="Rule", event_rule_arn='')
target = aws_events_targets.LambdaFunction(handler=lambdaFn)
target.bind(rule=rule)
```